# restriction of multivariate polynomial on hyperplane

Tags: polynomials

It's said that a linear polynomial in 2-D restricted on a line is a linear polynomial of one variable.

I believe it's also true that in an n-dimensional space, a degree-k polynomial restricted on an n-1 dimensional hyperplane is a degree-k polynomial of n-1 variables.

However, I just can't see why is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The following is true. If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ of $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$,  then its restriction to a subspace of dimension $m<n$ is a polynomial of degree *at most* $k$ in $m$ variables. The degree can be less than $k$.

Proof: a subspace of dimension $m$ is determined by $n-m$ independent linear equations in variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Use these relations to express $n-m$ variables in terms of the rest. Up to renumbering the variables, this means you'll have
$$
x_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^m c_{ij}x_j,\quad j=m+1,\dots,n
\tag1$$
Plugging (1) into $p$ we do not increase the degree of $p$, because each variable is replaced by a linear combination of others. Thus, the result is a polynomial of $x_1,\dots, x_m$ of degree *at most* $k$. We cannot rule out the possibility that the degree will decrease due to  cancellation of some terms.

For example, the restriction of cubic polynomial $p(x_1,x_2)=x_1^3-x_2^3+2x_1$ to the line $x_2=x_1$ is a linear polynomial, not a cubic one.